# Text on button disapear

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a problem with the text on my button, when I make the window smaller the text disappears. I want to make the window smaller but still see the text even if the button gets smaller. Here is my code

```html
<Page
    x:Class="Labb_2_Calculator.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Labb_2_Calculator"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid Background="WhiteSmoke" KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Background="White" Foreground="Black" IsReadOnly="True" Name="TextResault" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="160" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="1420" Margin="10" FontSize="100" Text="0"></TextBox>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Name="TextNumber" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  Grid.Column="3" Text="" FontSize="80" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30"></TextBlock>
        <Button Name="button1" Click="Button_Click" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="120">1</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_1" Grid.Column="1" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="120">2</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_2" Grid.Column="2" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="120">3</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_3" Grid.Column="3" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="120">+</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_4" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="120">4</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_5" Grid.Column="1" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="120">5</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_6" Grid.Column="2" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="120">6</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_7" Grid.Column="4" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="120">-</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_8" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Grid.Row="3" FontSize="120">7</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_9" Grid.Column="1" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Grid.Row="3" FontSize="120">8</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_10" Grid.Column="2" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Grid.Row="3" FontSize="120">9</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_11" Grid.Column="3" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Grid.Row="3" FontSize="120">X</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_12" Background="orange" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Grid.Row="4" FontSize="120" >C</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_13" Grid.Column="1" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Grid.Row="4" FontSize="120">0</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_14" Grid.Column="2" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Grid.Row="4" FontSize="120" >=</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_15" Grid.Column="3" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Grid.Row="4" FontSize="120">/</Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I have tried responsive fontsize like rem and % but it still does not work

Answer (score 2):

This should make the text in the button centered and scales it down if your button gets too small:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click_1" Name="button1" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="120">
    <Button.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Viewbox>
                <TextBlock>1</TextBlock>
            </Viewbox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

Just add the ContentTemplate code to each of your buttons and replace the Number with the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Proportional sizing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/layouts-with-xaml#layout-properties)(also called star sizing) in your Grid. Proportional sizing distributes available space among the rows and columns of a grid by weighted proportions. So actually, when you resize the window to make it smaller, the button didn't become smaller, it is still the same size. But the column width and the row height are smaller which makes the visible area of the button smaller. That's why you can't see the Text of the button.

It's recommended to use [adaptive layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/layouts-with-xaml#set-visual-states-in-xaml-markup) with state triggers. You could use [AdaptiveTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.adaptivetrigger?view=winrt-22621) to check the states and change your layout based on the width of the window, and then adjust the size of your buttons. This will be more friendly to users.

Here is a simple demo which show how it works

```
       <Grid Background="WhiteSmoke" >
       <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
           <VisualStateGroup>
               <VisualState x:Name="SmallSize">
               <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                   <AdaptiveTrigger  MinWindowWidth="500"/>
                   </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                   <VisualState.Setters>
                   <Setter Target="button1.Width" Value="100"/>
                   <Setter Target="button1.Height" Value="80"/>
                   <Setter Target="button1.FontSize" Value="20"/>
                       
                   </VisualState.Setters>
               </VisualState>
           <VisualState x:Name="BigSize">
               <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                   <AdaptiveTrigger  MinWindowWidth="1000"/>
               </VisualState.StateTriggers>

               <VisualState.Setters>
                   <Setter Target="button1.Width" Value="200"/>
                   <Setter Target="button1.Height" Value="160"/>
                   <Setter Target="button1.FontSize" Value="120"/>

               </VisualState.Setters>
           </VisualState>
       </VisualStateGroup>
       </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
       <Button Name="button1" Content="1"  Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="120"></Button>
     
   </Grid>
```

When you resize the window, you will see the button become smaller when the window width is less than 500.